If $G$ is a finitely generated pro-$\pi$ group, are its Sylow subgroups finitely generated?
This question asks if a Sylow subgroup of a finitely generated profinite group $G$ is also finitely generated. The answer is negative. The counterexample to the claim involves infinitely many primes. So, if we impose the condition "only finitely many primes divide $|G|$ is it still false?", I mean:

If $G$ is a finitely generated pro-$\pi$ group (for a finite set of primes $\pi$), are its Sylow subgroups finitely generated?


No. Let $C_n$ be cyclic of order $n$, and let $p,q$ be distinct primes, and $\pi=\{p,q\}$. Consider $G_n=C_p\wr C_{q^n}=C_p^{q^n}\rtimes C_{q^n}$ and let $G$ be the projective limit of $G_1\leftarrow G_2\leftarrow\dots$. Then $G$ is 2-generated (since each $G_n$ is) but its unique $p$-Sylow has infinite rank (since the rank of the $p$-Sylow in $G_n$ is $q^n$).
